# How do I create a unique_ptr from a raw pointer, by reference?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm calling a library function which returns a raw pointer to a class object, but I'd like to wrap the returned pointer in a `unique_ptr`. I don't know how the library creates the pointer, but I'm assuming that it uses `new` (see the comment in the code below).

Is the code below a valid way to create the `unique_ptr` and return it by reference from a function call? The code does print '42', but is there a better way to do this?

---

The library is the MariaDB [C++ connector](https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql/connect/programming-languages/cpp/development/). Unfortunately, it has minimal documentation. I asked about this on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75257433/6162729) a couple of days ago, but had no response so far. I'd use the MySQL version instead, but it doesn't seem to be much better. However, there is an [example program](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/dev-example-todo/blob/master/console/cpp/tasks.cpp), which includes this line in `main`:

```
std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> conn(driver->connect(url, properties));
```

So, having read the comments and the answer, I think I can now assume that the `Connection` object that I want was `new`ed. On the other point, of why I'm passing by reference instead of just returning the `unique_ptr` - good question. The only reason is that all the other code in this app returns a `bool` as a success status, so I thought it would be more consistent to do the same here.

Original code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
   int b;
   A() : b(42) {}
};

void create(std::unique_ptr<A> &p) {
   A *a = new A; // this is actually a function call which returns an A*
   p.reset(a);
}

int main() {
   std::unique_ptr<A> foo;
   create(foo);
   std::cout << "foo.b is " << foo->b << '\n';
}
```

Comment: *Why* handle it by reference? Why not `return std::unique_ptr<A>(library_call());` with by reference stuff so the caller can just do `auto foo = create();`? Even if the caller already created a `std::unique_ptr` and is updating it, the code is clearer, and not meaningfully slower, with `existingfoo = create();` using move-assignment to replace the pointer.

Comment: if you do not know that the pointer was created via new (ie object is on the heap) then you must not put it in a unique_ptr

Comment: *"but I'm assuming that it uses new"* - Best use public APIs over assumptions.

Comment: `I don't know how the library creates the pointer` the documentation of the library has to tell you how that pointer has to be handled. Otherwise you don’t know if it is valid to delete the object, and also not how.

Comment: @pm100: And it had better be *actually* `new`; if the library is making it with `malloc`/`calloc` (or even with array-based `new`, rather than individual object `new`), and you put it in a normal `unique_ptr` (which uses `delete`), you'll have problems even though they both "use the heap".

Comment: By default, `unique_ptr` uses delete, but it's possible to give it a custom deleter that can clean up the pointer in whatever way is appropriate.

Comment: @Kyle: Yep. But you need to *know* which one to use, you don't want to just assume it's `new`, especially if the library is offering a C compatible interface. Mismatched allocation and freeing APIs might actually work, in toy cases, because the heap corruption isn't immediately obvious, but you can't count on that in any program of meaningful size.

Comment: Even if it was created with `new` the library has to tell you if the ownership has been transphered to you, and also if it is valid to use `delete` or if it expects you to call a delete function provided by the library.

Comment: the doc of the library *must* say what to do with the pointer.

Comment: which library is it? Where does the pointer point to?

Comment: You have to find out, whether you or the library will delete the pointer. Even if it currently uses new; if it is not documented, the library could change in the next version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you wrote works ***if and only if*** the pointer is created with `new`. But even then, just `delete`'ing it may not be enough to uninitialize it properly, hence why you should **always** stick to managing this pointer in accordance with the library's documentation.

However, smart pointers are designed to account for cases like this, by allowing you to use a custom deleter function.

So, the proper way would be something like this:

```cpp
using my_ptr_t = std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A*)>;

void create(my_ptr_t& out) {
    A* a = ... // get the pointer
    out = my_ptr_t(a, [](A* p) -> void {
        // Uninitialize the pointer as dictated
        // by the library's documentation
        ...
    });
};
```